# Async Controller behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

`AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = value;` is assigning headlines value. But `headlines` are become null when `NewsCompleted` Method is being called.

```
public void NewsAsync(string city)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
        newsService.GetHeadlinesCompleted += (value) =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = value;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };
        newsService.GetHeadlinesAsync(city);
    }

    public ActionResult NewsCompleted(string[] headlines)
    {
        return View("News", new ViewStringModel
        {
            NewsHeadlines = headlines
        });
    }
```

1.)How can i debug this?

2.)And also when `OutstandingOperations` count become 0, framework calls my actionCompleted method, by requesting new thread from thread pool. When this actionCompleted method is called, I looked into call stack and have no idea that what is exactly happening behind. I mean how the framework knows it should call this particular actionCompleted method with this parameter from `AsyncManager`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these tweaks..

```
public void NewsAsync(string city)
{
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
    newsService.GetHeadlinesCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = args.Result;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    };
    newsService.GetHeadlinesAsync(city);
}

public ActionResult NewsCompleted(object headlines)
{
    return View("News", new ViewStringModel
    {
        NewsHeadlines = (string[])headlines
    });
}
```

Comment: Its working fine for me. But why should I change from string[] to object to make it work?

Comment: AsyncManager.Parameters is a IDictionary<string, Object>. When you items add to this, it gets added as object for the string key passed.

Comment: If you are using mvc 4 (framework 4.5), you can use the new async await constructs, which will make the controller code much much cleaner.